# Problem Configuring Static in OpenLiteSpeed with Django Project (www.menuweb.cl)

Tags: django, mime-types, openlitespeed

The problem.
traditional-italian-food-world-tourism-day.jpg:1 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
/#:1 - Refused to apply style from 'https://menuweb.cl/python/static/main/home.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I'm trying to set up a Django project on OpenLiteSpeed and am facing some challenges in properly configuring the static files.Based on the user manual's recommendations, I've set STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in my settings.py as follows:

STATIC_URL = '/python/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/growpyme/static'

Here's my directory structure:

```
/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/
```

- growpyme/
- staticfiles/
- main/
- static/
- carta/
- static/
- growpyme/
- static/

If anyone has previously configured Django static files in OpenLiteSpeed and can offer guidance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
{% load static %}
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>App Menu Web</title>
<!-- Incluir Bootstrap CSS y JS usando un CDN para mejor compatibilidad -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"       rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Vincula tus hojas de estilo CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/home.css' %}">

<!-- Vincula tus librerías o frameworks JS -->
<script src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?f...0&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"      rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```